Difference between $ac\bmod m = (a\bmod m*c\bmod m)\bmod m$ and $ac\bmod m = (a\bmod m*c)\bmod m$?
Doesn't $ac\bmod m = (a\bmod m*c\bmod m)\bmod m$ and $ac\bmod m = (a\bmod m*c)\bmod m$ return the same result which are both correct
The only difference I see is $(c\bmod m)$ reduces the multiplication with $(a\bmod m)$ in the first formula.
Is there any difference in the outputs for the two functions for any particular case?

Formatting note:  you need to put a pace between the \bmod and the modulus.  That is, "\bmod m" works but "\bmodm" doesn't.  Also:  the direction of the slash matters.

Thank you for the help, I hope the question is better understood now.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes they are equal - see the Key Idea in the linked dupe.
